# When uploading an asset, the asset is not selected after upload

Tags: assets

When uploading an asset through either the assets tab, or within an asset field - the asset uploads successfully but doesn't get automatically selected for insertion.

To get around the issue I have to search for asset filename and then select it.

Ideally the asset should get selected by default ready to be inserted by clicking 'select'.

We have quite a few assets, so there is auto pagination/load more which might be causing the issue?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try and have them ordered by "Date Modified - Descending", so that any new asset will always be on top of the list. Even if does not get selected automatically (could work because it's on the first pagination page), it's a very easy way to find it! ;)

Comment: This worked, the asset appeared at the top and was automatically selected.

Any way to make this the default setting for each asset upload folders?

Comment: I don't think so, John. Also keep in mind that this is a setting saved in the session cookie and not in the DB, so this has to be set up on each device.

Answer (score 1):

> We have quite a few assets, so there is auto pagination/load more which might be causing the issue?"

You nailed it. It's a known issue and we just haven't figured out a clean way to to select the items when they show up in a different page.

I'd suggest adding this to the feedback site as it feels more like a feature request than anything.

Comment: Does it help to have assets be ordered by date added desc?

Comment: Actually not sure!  Probably worth a quick test.

Comment: From our perspective it feels more like a bug - but with the solution of sorting by date modified, perhaps this could be made the default or an option to choose the default (other than going through and changing it for each folder in advance).

Comment: @JohnStewart I just added a feature request: [Make "Date Modified - Descending" the default sort order for assets](http://feedback.buildwithcraft.com/forums/285221-feature-requests/suggestions/7933224-make-date-modified-descending-the-default-sort).